# Why is my gradient not showing in the window with Java AWT

Tags: java, awt, gradient

**Background gradient not showing java awt**

I am trying to create a simple window with a gradient background. But i cannot figure out why is the gradient background not showing / drawing.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        
        Frame mainApp = new Frame("Paint");
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int screenWidth = (int)screenSize.getWidth(); int screenHeight = (int)screenSize.getHeight();
        //Defines window size
        Dimension windowSize = new Dimension(800, 800);
        //Defines window position
        Point windowPosition = new Point(
                screenWidth / 2 - (int)windowSize.getWidth() / 2,
                screenHeight / 2 - (int)windowSize.getHeight() / 2);
        
        //Defines a close function to close the app
        mainApp.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                mainApp.dispose();
            }
        });
        
        mainApp.setBounds(new Rectangle(windowPosition, windowSize));
        mainApp.setVisible(true);
        
        Graphics2D appGraphic = (Graphics2D)mainApp.getGraphics();
        GradientPaint background = new GradientPaint(0, 0,
                new Color(255, 0, 0),
                800,
                800,
                new Color(0, 0, 255)
                );
        appGraphic.setPaint(background);
        appGraphic.fillRect(0, 0, (int)windowSize.getWidth(), (int)windowSize.getHeight());
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: 1) AWT (and Swing) have a parent/child relationship between components. The frame is the top level component and it contains a "content pane" which contains the components. Therefore the painting of the content pane paints on top of the frame so you don't see the gradient. 2) Don't use getGraphic() on a component to do painting. That is only a temporary painting. The next time the component is painted it will be lost. 3) Instead I suggest you use Swing and read the [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) tutorial for the basics.

Comment: 3) See: [Using Top-Level Containers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) to better understand the parent/child relationship. 4) You can also search the site for examples that use the GradientPaint class.